# Oracle, PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UPDATE" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ;

Tags: oracle

I have encountered the following problem. Need help, please!

```
SQL> begin tran UPDATE 'Emp' SET 'Salary'=999;
  2  WHERE 'ID'=1
  3  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:20'
  4  ROLLBACK
  5  /
begin tran UPDATE 'Emp' SET 'Salary'=999;
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 12:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UPDATE" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;
```

The second transaction shows:

```
SQL> set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
  2  select Salary from Emp where ID=1;
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
                                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02179: valid options: ISOLATION LEVEL { SERIALIZABLE | READ COMMITTED }
```

Comment: If 'Emp' is a table name, remove the single quotes around its name

Comment: You can use back-ticks- ` ` , not the single-quotes- ' ' for table and column names.

Comment: Is this really Oracle? Looks like SQL Server to me. In Oracle you are always in a transaction. So simply use `UPDATE Emp SET Salary = 999;`. It seems you are trying to run SQL Server commands in Oracle which naturally fails.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner At least the error message is Oracle's, the statements in the question look like they belong to another RDBMS.

Comment: And Oracle [doesn't allow `read uncommitted`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/consist.htm#CNCPT1319). You're also missing a semicolon. You need to use valid syntax for the database you're using - code from another database system may not work without modification.

Comment: Yes, it is my fail. Iam use SQL Plus interpritator.